# Gradle task to build Jar excluding android classes

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar

I'm writing a simple Gradle task that should take all the intermediate classes and package them inside a `.jar` file, the task is inserted in a chain of gradle tasks that are used to build an Android library.

Please note that the Android library is not packaged in a `*.aar` archive, I have a few task that will build the jar, build a few shared object and place them in a directory.

The task I wrote so far is the following:

```
task createDevJarRelease(type: Jar) {
    from 'build/intermediates/classes/release'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'MYJar library',  
            'Implementation-Version': '1.0'
    }

    archiveName "my-jar.jar"
    doLast {
        // Copy the jar in the target directory.
        copy {
            include "my-jar.jar"
            from    "build/libs/"
            into    "targetDir"
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that the jar is properly created and placed in my `targetDir` BUT I won't be able to actually use it inside an android project, because the `jar` file contains, together with my classes, also other classes from android dependencies that causes clashes when included inside an Android application.

I went inside the `build/intermediates/classes/release` and noticed the following directory hierarchy:

```
build/intermediates/classes/release
    |_ android
    |  |_ arch
    |  |  |_ core
    |  |     |_ ...
    |  |  |_ lifecycle
    |  |     |_ ...
    |  |_ support 
    |    |_ ...
    |    |  |_ ...
    |    |_ ...
    |_ my
      |_ package
        |_ name
          |_ foo.class
          |_ bar.class
```

I've tried different solutions found online in order to exclude the classes beneath the `android` directory but with no success.

I tried explicitly adding the `exclude` command in the Gradle task above but didn't work at all (classes are still there).

```
exclude 'build/intermediates/classes/release/android'
```

---

The error seen when building the Application with this `jar` is:

```
> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/R;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/R;

com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/R;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

---

The project dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual solution for this was not to `exclude` the classes in the `jar` gradle task but to change the dependencies of the project, using `compileOnly` instead of `implementation` when setting the `com.android.support` dependency.

The fix is:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compileOnly 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```